# How to Read/Write Windows 7 Library Locations?

Tags: windows, delphi, registry

**Intro**

In Windows 7 you have some special folders for documents, pictures and music etc called Libraries.

If you are not aware of them, basically each Library folder can contain Locations (paths) which are basically shortcuts for each Library.

**Some examples:**

`Documents (Library)`

- E:\Personal\Documents `(Location)`
- F:\Backups\Documents `(Location)`

`Music (Library)`

- E:\Media\Music\Albums `(Location)`
- E:\Media\Music\Singles `(Location)`

`Pictures (Library)`

- E:\Media\Photos `(Location)`

When you click any of these Library folders from Windows Explorer or Start menu, Windows Explorer will show with the Locations defined inside that Library.

**Task**

What I need to be able to do is read the Locations for each Library type, and be able to write back (update) the Library with my own Locations. I have found that the Libraries are stored in the user AppData folder like this:

`C:\Users\SOMEUSER\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Libraries`

These Libraries are this file type: **Library (.library-ms)** - if you right click on one and select properties, Library tab you can see the Library locations associated with that Library.

I don't see a way of extracting these and putting them for example into a TStringList for editing in Delphi. I wondered if these Library Locations were actually stored in the Windows Registry so with some research from Google I found these paths:

- HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders
- HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders

But again, I don't see the actual list of Library Locations.

So, how can I read the list of Locations inside a Library file in Delphi, add them to a Listbox or TStringList, edit the entries and then write back the changes? Just been able to extract the Library Location paths would be a start.

I just have a feeling this is going to be one of those questions that has a simple answer I cannot seem to find!

Comment: Read about it on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/ee658250.aspx  and thenuse the APIs. Don't even think about hacking the implementation specific stuff.

Comment: I've just read somewhere that the .library-ms file could be an XML file, I've lost the page I was reading though!

Comment: You aren't meant to poke in those files. Use the API.

Comment: @Blobby today they are - tomorrow MS will remove files or change their format - and your application is screwed. If you don't aim at strategy "make bugs, sell fixes" a la BIND software, then you'd probably not make deliberately future-incompatible programs. Read how programs like that make Windows buggy and less stable: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2003/11/03/55532.aspx

Comment: @Arioch'The I just wanted to make the tool for myself, I regularly format and reinstall Windows 7 so manually resetting the library paths can be a pain, if I made a tool to automate this myself that is what I was hoping to do. I don't need to worry about MS changing anything because I know it is always going to be used on Windows 7

Comment: then you give it to your friend, then he gives it to his firend and so it spreads to Win8, Win9, ... Until having serious reasons one'd better avoid undocumented functions.

Comment: at my Win7 x64 those files are definitely XML. So what ? If i want to survive re-installs - i don't need to edit them. I just copy them to archive before reinstall and copy them back them after. If i need to make tool for editing them - then using official API would not be harder than using some XML library API. So i still can't see the reason to look inside those files other than mere curiosity.

Comment: You might want to see [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2012/08/28/10343980.aspx) at Raymond Chen's blog site. It's about a command-line utility (with source) that works with Win7 libraries; you might be able to handle things in a batch file or PowerShell script using it.

Comment: @Blobby: You should see Remy's additions to his answer, which are quite useful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use one of the `SHLoadLibraryFrom...()` functions, like `SHLoadLibraryFromKnownFolder()`, to get an `IShellLibrary` interface, then you can use its methods to enumerate and manipulate the Library, such as `IShellLibrary::GetFolders()`, `IShellLibrary::AddFolder()`, `IShellLibrary::RemoveFolder()`, etc.

**Update:** For example:

```
uses
  ..., ActiveX, KnownFolders, ShlObj;

// The SHLoadLibraryFrom...() functions are implemented inline in the Win32 SDK
// shobjidl.h header file, so you have to implement them manually in your 
// code if you you are not using a version of Delphi that already implements
// them in the RTL's ShlObj.pas unit for you...

// SHLoadLibraryFromKnownFolder() is defined wrong in ShlObj.pas!!! See QC #109306
function My_SHLoadLibraryFromKnownFolder(const kfidLibrary: TGUID; grfMode: DWORD; riid: TIID; out ppv): HRESULT;
var
  plib: IShellLibrary;
begin
  Result := CoCreateInstance(CLSID_ShellLibrary, nil, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IShellLibrary, plib);
  if SUCCEEDED(Result) then
  begin
    Result := plib.LoadLibraryFromKnownFolder(kfidLibrary, grfMode);
    if SUCCEEDED(Result) then
      Result := plib.QueryInterface(riid, ppv);
  end;
end;

function GetLibraryFileSystemFolders(FolderID: TGUID; Folders: TStrings): Boolean;
var
  SL: IShellLibrary;
  Arr: IShellItemArray;
  Enum: IEnumShellItems;
  Item: IShellItem;
  Path: LPWSTR;
begin
  Result := False;

  if FAILED(My_SHLoadLibraryFromKnownFolder(FolderID, STGM_READ, IShellLibrary, SL)) then
    Exit;

  if FAILED(SL.GetFolders(LFF_FORCEFILESYSTEM, IShellItemArray, Arr)) then
    Exit;

  if FAILED(Arr.EnumItems(Enum)) then
    Exit;

  while Enum.Next(1, Item, nil) = S_OK then
  begin
    if FAILED(Item.GetDisplayName(SIGDN_FILESYSPATH, Path)) then
      Exit;
    try
      Folders.Add(Path);
    finally
      CoTaskMemFree(Path); 
    end;
    Item := nil;
  end;

  Result := True;
end;
```

.

```
var
  Folders: TStringList;
begin
  Folders := TStringList.Create;
  try
    if GetLibraryFileSystemFolders(FOLDERID_DocumentsLibrary, Folders) then
    begin
      //...
    end;
  finally
    Folders.Free;
  end;
end;
```

**Update**: `SHLoadLibraryFromKnownFolder()` only works for Microsoft-defined Libraries that have `KNOWNFOLDERID` values defined.  If you want to access custom Libraries, you have to use a slightly modified approach to obtaining the `IShellLibrary` interface, eg:

```
// SHLoadLibraryFromItem() is defined wrong in ShlObj.pas!!! See QC #109306
function My_SHLoadLibraryFromItem(const psiLibrary: IShellItem; grfMode: DWORD; const riid: TIID; out ppv): HResult;
var
  plib: IShellLibrary;
begin
  Result := CoCreateInstance(CLSID_ShellLibrary, nil, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IShellLibrary, plib);
  if Succeeded(Result) then
  begin
    Result := plib.LoadLibraryFromItem(psiLibrary, grfMode);
    if Succeeded(Result) then
      Result := plib.QueryInterface(riid, ppv);
  end;
end;

function GetShellLibraryforLibrary(const LibraryName: String; grfMode: DWORD; var ppv: IShellLibrary): Boolean;
var
  SL: IShellLibrary;
  Enum: IEnumShellItems;
  Item: IShellItem;
  DisplayName: LPWSTR;
  hr: HRESULT;
begin
  Result := False;
  ppv := nil;

  if FAILED(SHGetKnownFolderItem(FOLDERID_Libraries, 0, 0, IShellItem, PPointer(@Item)^) then
    Exit;

  hr := Item.BindToHandler(nil, BHID_EnumItems, IEnumShellItems, Enum);
  if FAILED(hr) then
    Exit;

  Item := nil;
  while Enum.Next(1, Item, nil) = S_OK do
  begin
    if FAILED(Item.GetDisplayName(SIGDN_NORMALDISPLAY, DisplayName)) then
      Exit;
    try
      if AnsiSameText(DisplayName, LibraryName) then
      begin
        Result := SUCCEEDED(My_SHLoadLibraryFromItem(Item, grfMode, IShellLibrary, ppv));
        Break;
      end;
    finally
      CoTaskMemFree(DisplayName);
    end;
    Item := nil;
  end;
end;

function GetLibraryFileSystemFolders(const LibraryName: String; Folders: TStrings): Boolean;
var
  SL: IShellLibrary;
  Arr: IShellItemArray;
  Enum: IEnumShellItems;
  Item: IShellItem;
  Path: LPWSTR;
begin
  Result := False;

  if not GetShellLibraryforLibrary(LibraryName, STGM_READ, SL) then
    Exit;

  if FAILED(SL.GetFolders(LFF_FORCEFILESYSTEM, IShellItemArray, Arr)) then
    Exit;

  if FAILED(Arr.EnumItems(Enum)) then
    Exit;

  while Enum.Next(1, Item, nil) = S_OK then
  begin
    if FAILED(Item.GetDisplayName(SIGDN_FILESYSPATH, Path)) then
      Exit;
    try
      Folders.Add(Path);
    finally
      CoTaskMemFree(Path); 
    end;
    Item := nil;
  end;

  Result := True;
end;
```

.

```
var
  Folders: TStringList;
begin
  Folders := TStringList.Create;
  try
    if GetLibraryFileSystemFolders('MyLibrary', Folders) then
    begin
      //...
    end;
  finally
    Folders.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Have you got a Delphi example of doing this, Remy?

Comment: This is the type of problem where the C++ examples are likely to be better quality. It's essential to be able to read and understand C++ to learn Windows APIs well.

Comment: @David, while that might be true in general, this question is tagged `Delphi`. :-)

Comment: I have added an example that loads a Library's file system paths.  I will leave the rest as an exercise for you to figure out.

Comment: @Ken The tagging of this question isn't really the point. My point is that a Delphi programmer will be constrained if only prepared to learn from Delphi samples.

Comment: @David most WinAPI is C, not C++. Thankfully, WinAPI is not Qt :-)

Comment: @Arioch That's not really accurate. The Windows API is language neutral. It is not written in any language. It is an interface. Most of the samples are C or C++. This interface is COM and that tends to push people to c++ rather than C. Doing COM in C is no fun at all.

Comment: @David I don't think it is language neutral. Try to use it from Logo or pure Lisp. Let's say it uses "common subset" of modern imperative languages, that is very similar to C (as in "machine-independent assembler" ;-) )  Writing COM in pure C, like in pure Pascal w/o IDispatch sugar, would be very tedious. But reading COM-related code in pure C would be easer than C++, if you just need to translate the sample to your language. You can skip decrypting given C++ implementation syntactic sugar and see API usage as is.

Comment: @Arioch No, it's language neutral at the interface level. It doesn't mandate any specific language. COM is much easier to implement and consume in C++ than in C. Primarily because you can use method syntax. COM does not require IDispatch. No IDispatch here. IDispatch is something else.

Comment: @David, sorry, but you're wrong. The vast majority of the **WinAPI** is based on C, and the examples for that functionality is C. The interfaces that are offered (particularly with the Windows shell) are C++ based, because (as ugly as it is) C++ is much more interface-friendly than C. I'm very fluent in C and some other languages, but the interface stuff is still nasty; having Delphi examples available to help understand it is very useful. And Delphi supports COM as well (if not better) than C++, once you get going on the learning curve (which I admit I haven't yet).

Comment: @KenWhite If the examples don't exist in Delphi code, then do you give up? No, you learn to read them in C or C++, or even C#, and then map that across to your Delphi code. You are better off learning from a well written and comprehensive C++ sample code, than an incomplete and poorly written Delphi sample code. If there exists a good Delphi sample code, then so much the better. If you can't read and translate C, C++ and C# code to Delphi then that will sometimes hold you back.

Comment: @KenWhite For Win7 libraries, the best set of code samples I know is in C#. In the Windows API CodePack. I think `IShellLIbrary` is in older Delphis. Marco's 2010 handbook gets it from `ShlObj`. There's oodles of hits for a websearch for `IShellLIbrary` and Delphi.

Comment: This all looks a lot harder than I had anticipated!

Comment: @Ken - This code is fine with XE2. use 'activex' and 'knownfolders' besides 'shlobj', define 'REFIID=TIID' and 'REFKNOWNFOLDERID=TGUID', uncomment 'SHLoadLibraryFromKnownFolder' function, and substitute something for 'Library' (reserved word).   And thanks to Remy for correcting the crappy 'SHLoadLibraryFromKnownFolder' in 'shlobj.pas' in XE2.

Comment: @KenWhite: I didn't want to waste my time tracking down all of the various inter-dependant constants and type declarations just for a simple example. If someone doesn't have a Delphi version that already has all of the relevant declarations available, they can track them down themselves. Hense my earlier comment of "I will leave the rest as an exercise for you to figure out".

Comment: @RemyLebeau: I understand (having looked at it myself today). :-) I'd forgotten I made that reference in my comment above; I'll delete it, because it sounds more critical than I intended anyway. (It was before coffee this morning.) :-)

Comment: I never understand any of this API stuff, it baffles me how some people can understand and write code like this.

Comment: API programming by itself is really not that difficult. Shell programming, on the other hand, can be fairly complex, not counting the complexities of ActiveX/COM that Shell interfaces are based on.

Comment: @David: Thanks for both the CodePack and the DH2010 mention. I wasn't familiar with the first, and I have the second (but never actually looked at it - it was a free download with D2010, IIRC).

Comment: @Remy: You should update this answer with the code you recently provided in the EMBT forums (https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?threadID=76884&tstart=0).

Answer (score 1):

I have just found in Marco Cantu's source code repository for his Mastering Delphi books, an example for Delphi 2010 which shows a way of getting the locations inside a library.

The link to the repository is here: http://code.marcocantu.com/p/marcodelphibooks/source/tree/HEAD/

In the `delphi2010handbook`, `chapter 05 (Win7Libraries)` is the example source.

The method used in that demo is basically the use of the Windows API that has already been mentioned, the demo confirms that the Library files are indeed of XML format.

---

Additionally I found the following information which is quite useful:

- **SHAddFolderPathToLibrary** - Adds a folder to a library.
- **SHCreateLibrary IShellLibrary** - Creates an object.
- **SHLoadLibraryFromItem** - Creates and loads IShellLibrary to object from a specified library definition file.
- **SHLoadLibraryFromKnownFolder** - Creates and loads of IShellLibrary object for a specified KNOWNFOLDERID.
- **SHLoadLibraryFromParsingName** - Creates and loads of IShellLibrary object for a specified path.
- **SHRemoveFolderPathFromLibrary** - Removes a folder from a library.
- **SHResolveFolderPathInLibrary** - Attempts to resolve the target location of a library folder that has been moved or renamed.
- **SHResolveLibrary** - Attempts to find the location of a library.
- **SHSaveLibraryInFolderPath** - Saves on IShellLibrary object to disk.
- **SHShowManageLibraryUI** - Shows the library management dialog, Which Enables users to manage the library folders and default save location.