# What is the correct way to detect that an IShellItem refers to a Library?

Tags: windows, winapi

I'm using the common file dialog with `FOS_PICKFOLDERS` to let the user pick a location to save files. If the user selects a library, e.g. `Library\Documents` then my current code fails at the point where I call `IShellItem::GetDisplayName` to extract a file system name. If the item were a file then this would succeed and the library's default save location would be used.

What I would like to do is to detect that the shell item is a library, then obtain an `IShellLibrary` interface, and then query it to find the default save location. Then I would save my files there.

What is the correct way to detect that an `IShellItem` refers to a Library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I found was to use `IShellLibrary::LoadLibraryFromItem` ([MSDN here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/dd391720%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)), to which you pass an `IShellItem` interface.

If it fails (i.e. `HRESULT != S_OK`), then the `IShellItem` is *not* a library.

So something like this:

```
bool IsLibrary(IShellItem *pItem)
{
    bool bIsLibrary = false;

    IShellLibrary *plib = NULL;
    HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_ShellLibrary, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, 
        IID_PPV_ARGS(&plib));
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = plib->LoadLibraryFromItem(pItem, STGM_READ);
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) bIsLibrary = true;
        plib->Release();
    }
    return bIsLibrary;
}
```

I have no idea if it's the "correct" way, but it may be useful anyway.

Comment: It is the correct solution. You can simplify the code using the [`SHLoadLibraryFromItem()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/dd378434.aspx) wrapper function.

Answer (score 5):

Use [`SHLoadLibraryFromItem()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/dd378434.aspx) to get an `IShellLibrary` from an `IShellItem`, eg:

```
IShellItem *pItem, *pSave;
IShellLibrary *pLibrary;
...
if (SUCCEEDED(SHLoadLibraryFromItem(pItem, STGM_READWRITE, IID_IShellLibrary, (void**)&pLibrary)))
{
    pLibrary->GetDefaultSaveFolder(DSFT_DETECT, IID_IShellItem, (void**)&pSave);
    pLibrary->Release();
}
else
{
    pSave = pItem;
    pSave->AddRef();
}
...
pSave->GetDisplayName(...);
pSave->Release();
```

Comment: +1 and thanks. Too bad I cannot use `SHLoadLibraryFromItem` from the Delphi RTL, although of course it's very easy to roll your own.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: `SHLoadLibraryFromItem()` is declared in Delphi's `ShlObj.pas` unit in recent versions. However, it is [implemented wrong](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=109306), which we have [discussed before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12485427/how-to-read-write-windows-7-library-locations) and I did provide a working implementation.

Comment: I (re)discovered all this earlier today. You working implementation is over complex. The `QueryInterface` call can be eliminated since you ask for `IShellLibrary` when calling `CoCreateInstance`.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: The implementation is Microsoft's, I merely made it work correctly in Delphi since Embarcadero's is broken. `IShellLibrary` can be queried for other interfaces, not to mention the reference count of the output needs to be incremented no matter what, so that is why `QueeryInterface()` is needed separate from `CoCreateInstance()`.

Comment: It may well be MS implementation, but it doesn't need to be that complex. You don't need to increment the reference count of the interface returned by `CoCreateInstance`, to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: Like I said, the created `IShellLibrary` object can be queried for other interfaces, not just `IShellLibrary`. That is why the `SHLoadLibraryFrom...()` functions have an IID parameter at all, otherwise it would be a redundant parameter. `QueryInterface()` on a `IShellLibrary` has to check for `IID_IShellLibrary` internally anyway, so it is actually more complex and redundant to have `SHLoadLibraryFrom...()` skip the `QueryInterface()` if `IID_IShellLibrary` is being requested, not to mention requiring a second code branch to avoid issues with Delphi's interface reference counting semantics.